# Watir - page object gem - arguments not been passed from step definition steps

Tags: watir, page-object-gem

I am using Cheezy's page object gem but having trouble passing arguments from my step definition to my page object method.

step_definition folder - login_steps.rb:

```
When(/^I enter the correct details$/) do
  on(LoginPage).login_with 'user@email.com' , 'password'
end
```

login_page.rb:

```
class LoginPage < BasePage
  include PageObject

  page_url = "https://somepage.com/login"

  text_field(:username_email_field, :class=>"topcoat-text-input ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-email")
  text_field(:password_field, :class=>"topcoat-text-input ng-pristine ng-valid")
  button(:login_button, :value=>"Login")
  button(:forgot_pass_button, :class=>"forgottenPasswordBtn topcoat-button")

  def login_with(username_email_field,password_field)
    self.username_email_field = username_email_field
    self.password_field = password_field
    login_button
  end
```

Console:

```
 Scenario: Registered User logs in         # login_page.feature:10
 And I am registered for an event        # features/step_definitions/login_steps.rb:5
 When I enter the correct login details  # features/step_definitions/login_steps.rb:9
   wrong number of arguments (0 for 2) (ArgumentError)
   ./features/support/page_objects/login_page.rb:20:in `login_with'
   ./features/step_definitions/login_steps.rb:10:in `/^I enter the correct login details$/'
   login_page.feature:12:in `When I enter the correct login details'
 Then I am taken the Event Schedule page # features/step_definitions/login_steps.rb:13
```

Not sure if my understanding is not complete on how this gem works or i have missed something simple.
thanks

Comment: I think you are looking at the wrong step definition. The Cucumber report says that the failed step is "When I enter the correct login details", but the step definition shared is for "When I enter the correct details". Notice that one is "login details" and the other is just "details".

Comment: Hi, yes you are right, school boy error on my part. Thanks very much.